# How to wrap Tensorflow by Cython and enable C++ to call it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cython

Sometimes I'd like to build the Tensorflow application as a dynamic linked library so that it can be called by other C++ applications.  Although I can use [*Tensorflow C++ API*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide) to build the data flow graph, I'd prefer to use it's *Python API* because many shared models are written by that.

Following is one of my approaches that use Cython to wrap the Tensorflow application.  However, it ended up with "tensorflow.pxd not found" error.

### Detail

At first, here is the python code:

```
#File Name: HelloTensorflow.pyx

cimport numpy as np
cimport tensorflow as tf

cdef public float ExecuteTensorFlow():
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 2])
        w = tf.constant([0.2, 0.3], tf.float32)
        b = tf.constant( -0.1, tf.float32)
        linearModel = tf.matmul(x, tf.reshape(w, shape=[2, 1])) + b

        session = tf.Session()
        result = session.run(linearModel, feed_dict={x: np.reshape([-0.1, -0.4], [1, 2])} )

        return np.reshape(result, [])
```

and the C++ source code that will call it:

```
// File Name: CppCallPython.cpp

#include <Python.h>
#include "HelloTensorflow.h"
#include <iostream>

void Run(void)
{
        Py_Initialize();
        initHelloTensorflow();
                std::cout<<"\t Execute Tensorflow:\n";
                float result = ExecuteTensorFlow();
                std::cout<<"\t Result = "
                         <<result<<std::endl;
        Py_Finalize();
}

int main(void)
{
        ::Run();
}
```

and build the python code to the dynamic library by:

```
# File Name: createPythonLib.py

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup( ext_modules = cythonize("HelloTensorflow.pyx") )
```

Finally, use Makefile to execute the build:

```
# File Name: Makefile
Target = CppCallPython

# Compiler
CC = LC_MESSAGES=C g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g

LIB_PYTHON2 = $(shell python2-config --cflags --ldflags)
MODULE_NAME = HelloTensorflow
LIB_MODULE = -L./ $(MODULE_NAME).so


.PHONY: all
all: pythonLib  cppExecutable
        echo Build Finished.

pythonLib:
        python createPythonLib.py  build_ext --inplace

cppExecutable: $(MODULE_NAME).h
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(Target).cpp $(LIB_MODULE)  $(LIB_PYTHON2)  -o $(Target)
```

As mentioned above, it ended up with "tensorflow.pxd not found" error:

```
missing cimport in module 'tensorflow': HelloTensorflow.pyx
Compiling HelloTensorflow.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing HelloTensorflow.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport numpy as np
cimport tensorflow as tf
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

HelloTensorflow.pyx:2:8: 'tensorflow.pxd' not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createPythonLib.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup( ext_modules = cythonize("HelloTensorflow.pyx") )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: HelloTensorflow.pyx
makefile:18: recipe for target 'pythonLib' failed
make: *** [pythonLib] Error 1
```

Does this mean that I can't wrap Tensorflow application with Cython, because the "*.pxd" is not provided by Tensorflow?  Is there any other way?

### System

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
Tensorflow 1.2.0 GPU 
gcc version 5.4.0 
Python: Python 2.7.12 
Cython version 0.23.4

Comment: Do you need to construct your graph from C++, or do you just need to be able to execute it? If it's the latter then a much easier solution would be to construct the graph in Python, save it to disk, and then load it and execute it in C++ (see [here](https://tebesu.github.io/posts/Training-a-TensorFlow-graph-in-C++-API), for example).

Comment: Thanks!  I think this can solve my question!  Would you answer the question formally so that I can vote you up?

PS. At the first glance, I thought you want me to synchronize the return value through IO which is kind of slow.  After a while, I realize what you mean is to build the graph in python.  Then read the graph from C++ and do the calculation so that the calculation can be real-time if the network is small.  Never thought about it, thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

`cimport` is a Cython-specific mechanism for importing statically defined type information from a pxd file. It does not look like tensorflow provides such a file (hence the error message). It looks like you're just using tensorflow as a Python module, in which case you should `import` it instead (this probably also applies to numpy too: it does define a .pxd file, but to access the normal numpy functions you should also `import` it).

Give that all your code is basically untyped Python code you should not expect huge speed improvements from using Cython.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  If I change the "cimport tensorflow" to "import tensorflow", it can compile and link successfully.  However, it will not recognize tensorflow at the runtime:

Exception NameError: "name 'tf' is not defined" in 'HelloTensorflow.ExecuteTensorFlow' ignored

Comment: Moreover, I'm not trying to speed up my python code here.  The reason why I try to compile python code to dynamic linked library is that I want other applications that are not written by python can call it as well.  For example, if I want the game engine (such as Unity3D) to call Tensorflow and get its return value, I should probably wrap the python code as *.so.  Or, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @WhiteRivers I'm slightly surprised that you get a `NameError` instead of an `ImportError` earlier. To try to get a more helpful error try adding `if (PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();` after `initHelloTensorflow();` in your C++ code.

Comment: @WhiteRivers Compiling the code in Cython still means you depend on libpython and having the python libraries that you use (like Tensorflow and numpy) installed, so it might not be the best solution for what you want. I don't know enough about Tensorflow to have a better solution though.